# Starting activity using thread

Tags: android, eclipse, multithreading

Like the title tells i am having problems running this app on my android Galaxy Ace S5830i.

1. I have just created a new android application in eclipse.
2. Added Splash.java in First-->src-->com.example.first-->Splash.java
3. Added a layout res-->layout-->splash.xml (it's basically just a copy of activity_fullscreen.xml set up by eclipse already just the button has been deleted)
4. Added some code in manifest

Whenever i start the app on device it crashes saying
"The application First (process com.example.first) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

As much i can tell you that the splash activity is started but crashes when trying to start the other activity.

Splash.java

```
    package com.example.first;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent start = new Intent("com.example.first.FullscreenActivity");
                startActivity(start);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

}

splash.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" >

<!--
     The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc.
-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:text="@string/dummy_content"
    android:textColor="#33b5e5"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!--
     This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.first"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.first.FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.first.Splash"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: change to this in your manifest `<action android:name="com.example.first.FullscreenActivity" />` and check http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html. check for implicit and explicit intents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On splash.class, change

```
Intent start = new Intent("com.example.first.FullscreenActivity");
```

to

```
Intent start = new Intent(Splash.this,com.example.first.FullscreenActivity.class);
```

And you manifest.xml change to following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.first"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.first.Splash"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.first.FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is the method i was using has been changed because the tutorials that i was following are somewhat old and it used that method in them.

Comment: @LakshayChhikara is not the method get to know implicit and explicit intents http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: Maybe... If my code is works, then you should forgot about what tutorials write.

Comment: Don't forget to check the answer if you think it is helpful. Thank you

Comment: Well it did work without changing the above manifest code. But it would be helpful if you can tell why you told to change it like this. All i can figure out is that you removed intent-filter and changed the positions of splash and FullscreenActivity.

Comment: Intent can be widely used as starting other apps activity, redirect to browser, and other... 

What are you doing right now is change activity from your own apps to your own apps. So you must declare in  Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) instead of Intent(String)

Comment: For more information, you can check the intent constructor
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String)